# Automated Testing with Databases

Tags: node.js, postgresql, testing, sequelize.js, jestjs

I'm fairly new to automated testing and was wondering how I should go about writing tests for the database. The project I'm working on right now is running PostgreSQL with Sequelize as the ORM on a Node.JS environment. If it matters, I'm also using Jest as the testing library right now.

Comment: You shouldn't "write tests for the database" so to speak. You should write tests for your own code. Then, that code may interact with that database. You'd have a separate test database that your code connects to when you're in test mode, so that your tests don't change the data in your development database.

Comment: FWIW - when writing tests for code that uses sequelize I usually sub in sqlite for my "real" database. I can give an example for Mocha if that is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys! @doublesharp an example would be really helpful and much appreciated!

So if I'm reading this right, I should have a "mock" database that I run my functions for read/write/update/delete requests to and test the response from that. Is there an easy way to point my automated tests to my "mock" database?

Comment: Mocking is a bit different - you still want to use `sequelize` but swap out `sqlite` as an in memory implementation. Mocking means that you are swapping out one module for another - for example I use `ioredis` to access Redis in production but `fakeredis` for testing. I mock `ioredis` so that when you `require()` it you get `fakeredis` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my app I use a `config` module to control configuration settings for different environments. When running tests the `process.env.APP_ENV` is set to `test`, and it will set the `dialect` to `sqlite`. Note that you will not have any data or data persistence, so you will need to populate it with all the data needed for your tests.

**Include sqlite3**

> `yarn add -D sqlite3`

or

> `npm i -D sqlite3`

**Config**

```js
module.exports = {
  database: {
    name: 'dbname',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'host',
    // Use "sqlite" for "test", the connection settings above are ignored
    dialect: process.env.APP_ENV === 'test' ? 'sqlite' : 'mysql',
  },
};
```

**Database/Sequelize**

```js
// get our config
  const config = require('../config');
  
  // ... code

  const instance = new Sequelize(
      config.database.name,
      config.database.user,
      config.database.password,
      {
        host: config.database.host,
        // set the dialect, will be "sqlite" for "test"
        dialect: config.database.dialect,
      }
  );
```

**Test Class (Mocha)**

```js
const TestUtils = require('./lib/test-utils');
    
describe('Some Tests', () => {
  let app = null;

  // run before the tests start
  before((done) => {
    // Mock up our services
    TestUtils.mock();

    // these are instantiated after the mocking
    app = require('../server');

    // Populate redis data
    TestUtils.populateRedis(() => {
      // Populate db data
      TestUtils.syncAndPopulateDatabase('test-data', () => {
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  // run code after tests have completed
  after(() => {
    TestUtils.unMock();
  });

  describe('/my/route', () => {
    it('should do something', (done) => {
      return done();
    });
  });
});
```

**Run Tests**

> `APP_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha`

You could use ENV variables in other ways to set the dialect and connection parameters as well - the above is just an example based on what we have done with a lot of supporting code.

Comment: You shouldn't use different DB backends between your test and other environments. As then you are not doing a true test of what your production environment might be.

Comment: @coler-j it depends on what you are testing. our ci/cd tools run docker and mimic a production environment to run tests before deployments, but there are cases where  you might want to test isolated unrelated functionality (this is less true if you are able to use docker or similar though)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything particularly complicated on the DB side, take a look at pg-mem:

- https://swizec.com/blog/pg-mem-and-jest-for-smooth-integration-testing/
- https://github.com/oguimbal/pg-mem

It's really cool in that it tests actual PG syntax and can pick up a bunch of errors that using a different DB or mock DB won't pick up. However, it's not a perfect implementation and missing a bunch of features (e.g. triggers, decent "not exists" handling, lots of functions) some of which are easy to work around with the hooks provided and some aren't.

For me, having the test DB initialized with the same schema initialization scripts as the real DB is a big win.